# Is there a non one-way quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-circuit, information-theory

Be it theoretical proposal or anything else, *is there even a definition for non one-way (or non measurement-based) quantum computer/computation?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual [circuit model for quantum computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_circuit#:%7E:text=In%20quantum%20information%20theory%2C%20a%20quantum%20circuit%20is,referred%20to%20as%20an%20n%20-%20qubit%20register.?msclkid=bb5ada7bbdaa11ec9d390cda86150061) is *not* a one-way quantum computation model. Hence it is an example of a non one-way model of computation.

The difference between a one-way quantum computation and circuit model quantum computation is that the second is described in terms of unitary operations, while the first is described in terms of adaptive measurements (sometimes non-destructive as well).

Maybe you are confused with the one-way terminology? The one-way model is 'one-way' in the sense that you must have all nonclassical resources at the start (large graph entangled state) because after each measurement these correlations are destroyed and cannot be reconstructed with other local projective measurements. Measurement Based Quantum Computation is an example of a one-way model of computation. It is interesting that you ask for the existence of a *non* one-way model because it was - as far as I know - quite surprising that quantum theory even allows for a one-way model of computation that is universal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, indeed I was confused with the concept of one-way quantum computation. So can I say that the conventional quantum circuit computation is NOT a one-way quantum computation because initially one has not prepared all the resource states (quantum states) in the beginning?

Comment: Yes you can say that, in the circuit model you only start with generic ancillas in the ground state $\vert 0 \rangle$ and uses unitary gates to perform the computation that you are particularly interested. So, it is not one-way. There is no problem, I am very happy that I could help.